# How do I add a graft to a gitlab repository?

Tags: git

I have in my local repository a `.git/info/grafts` to work around an oversight made when the repository was first created.

Now I would like to add this graft information to our upstream repo hosted on an internal gitlab server.  What is the procedure for adding a graft to a repository hosted on gitlab?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't.

You have to either:

- rewrite the complete history with `git filter-branch` and force push (but modify the history is not always possible and could cause a lot of problems)
- don't use the graft feature but prefer the 'replace' one...that you could push.

Comment: using filter-branch changes the commit hashes.  I performed an experiment using filter-branch and the test repo I pushed to ended up with two separate copies of the commit chain.  I consider this technique a disaster.  I am pretty sure rebasing has the same problem.

Comment: yes. But perhaps you don't understand what "modify the history" means. If you want to keep same sha1, that's the `replace` feature that you **must** use!